# Button draws image for only a second

Tags: python, pygame

So I been trying make it so when I press my button it draws my image forever, but nothing is happening:https://gyazo.com/83017705fa2b3f40ca26112a153791c5 I'm pressing my button but nothing is happening, I want it to draw my image and make my image stay when I press my button

This is what I tried

```
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            
    if Abutton.clicked:
        Abutton.clicked = True
        window.blit(A,(0,0))
```

My full code

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

# Drawing window screen
window = pygame.display.set_mode((700,500))
# The Name of my window
pygame.display.set_caption("StickMan")
# Drawing the buttons
A = pygame.image.load("A.png")
A2 = pygame.image.load("A1.png")

# Button class
class button1():
    def __init__(self, color, x,y,width,height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text
        self.clicked = False
    def draw(self,window,outline=None):
        #Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, outline, (self.x-2,self.y-2,self.width+4,self.height+4),0)
 
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, (self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height),0)
 
        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0,0,0))
            window.blit(text, (self.x + (self.width/2 - text.get_width()/2), self.y + (self.height/2 - text.get_height()/2)))
 
    def isOver(self, pos):
        #Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
        if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
            if pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                return True
 
            return False
 
    def playSoundIfMouseIsOver(self, pos, sound):
        if self.isOver(pos):            
            if not self.over:
                eat.play()
                self.over = True
        else:
            self.over = False

# Color
white = (255,255,255)


def redrawwindow():
    window.fill((0,0,0))

    

    
    Abutton = button1((0,255,0),287,310,55,55, '')

    Abutton.draw(window)

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            
    if Abutton.clicked:
        Abutton.clicked = True
        window.blit(A,(0,0))



run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False


        

    redrawwindow()
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part of your code:

```
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            
        if Abutton.isOver(pos):
            window.blit(A,(0,0))
```

you are telling pygame to only draw `A` when you click. Simply set a variable, like `self.clicked = False`, and add `self.clicked = True` in the `if` statement. Then, instead of drawing `A` in the `if` block, move it out:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        
if self.clicked:
    window.blit(A,(0,0))
```

---

If you only want the image to show while the mouse is over the button, simply change `event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` to `event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION`.

---

**QUESTION EDITED; NEW ANSWER:**

The main problem is that you defined your `Abutton` *inside* the `redrawwindow` function.
Because you call the function during each iteration of the `for` loop, the purpose of the
`self.clicked` variable is lost, as in every iteration of the `while` loop, the `Abutton` is redefined
with `self.clicked` set to `False`.

A tip: in your `isOver` function, you can directly return the expression, as the expression returns a bool value.

The working code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

# Drawing window screen
window = pygame.display.set_mode((700,500))
# The Name of my window
pygame.display.set_caption("StickMan")
# Drawing the buttons
A = pygame.image.load("A.png")
A2 = pygame.image.load("A1.png")

# Button class
class button1():
    def __init__(self, color, x,y,width,height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text
        self.clicked = False
    def draw(self,window,outline=None):
        #Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, outline, (self.x-2,self.y-2,self.width+4,self.height+4),0)
 
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, (self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height),0)
 
        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0,0,0))
            window.blit(text, (self.x + (self.width/2 - text.get_width()/2), self.y + (self.height/2 - text.get_height()/2)))
 
    def isOver(self, pos):
        #Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
        return pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width and pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height
 
    def playSoundIfMouseIsOver(self, pos, sound):
        if self.isOver(pos):            
            if not self.over:
                eat.play()
                self.over = True
        else:
            self.over = False

# Color
white = (255,255,255)
Abutton = button1((0,255,0),287,310,55,55, '')

def redrawwindow():
    window.fill((0,0,0))
    Abutton.draw(window)
    if Abutton.clicked:
        window.blit(A,(0,0))


run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if Abutton.isOver(pos):
                Abutton.clicked = True
    redrawwindow()
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```